# Resize image thumbnails dynamically based on window size, full-bleed

Tags: javascript, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to display a series of image thumbnails in a manner used on this website (a SquareSpace theme I believe): http://hellomattstevens.com/

I'm also using Bootstrap for my site's framework. What's the lightest, simplest solution to achieve this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><img src="someimage.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="someimage.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="someimage.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="someimage.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="someimage.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="someimage.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="someimage.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The challenge here is the dynamic sizing of images to get a constant bleed across the window.

Comment: view source their page see how they do it, look through the embedded and included scripts, and try to implement it

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues are you running into? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: Rather hard to look through compressed code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap offers a fluid width layout option to allow you to go full width. Have a look at the fluid-container section of their Docs:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You could then use this in conjunction with their Thumbnail code to layout your images:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails

Comment: The fluid container options is great, but I need to understand how the images on the site referenced are resized dynamically to maintain the full-width span for the page.

Comment: I think you would add the Bootstrap .img-responsive class on to each image thus allowing them to scale up or down responsively. All the images would have to be the same size and aspect ration (probably a square) when uploaded.

Comment: That's the route I headed down initially, but it doesn't work. The images don't resize dynamically based on window size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row img-height">
       <img rsc="image path" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row img-height">
       <img rsc="image path" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row img-height">
       <img rsc="image path" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.img-height {
 max-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't display images across the page horizontally.